# Construct object via __init__ and ignore constructor exception

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a Python class whose `__init__` method raises a custom exception called `WrongFileSpecified`.

However, when I write a unit test, I want to assign the attributes of the instance object from a test fixture. So normally what I would be doing is reading data off a file and then working with the instance object.

But with the test, I cannot use any test files, so I basically need to hard code the data in the instance object in the `setUp` method of the unit test. Is there any way to get a instance created without `__init__` complaining about the exception?

Sample code:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, folderPath):
        #check folder path using os.isdir() otherwise raise exception
        #...
        self.folderPath = folderPath
        #Call load record
        self._load_records() #uses self.folderPath and raises exceptions as well

        #Note i cannot avoid raising these exceptions, its required

class TestA(unittest.TestCase):
   .......
   obj = None
   def setUp(self):
        obj = A('fake folder path')
        obj.val1 = "testparam1"
        obj.param2 = "testparam2"

   def test_1(self):
.....
```

Comment: Why don't you move the logic for reading data from a file out to a class method, so you'd call e.g. `MyClass.from_file(whatever_file)` rather than `MyClass(whatever_file)`?

Comment: please post your code, this sounds like it will benefit from a redesign to allow it to be testable?

Comment: Can't post the code sorry non disclosure but I'll write a sample version up in a few mins

Comment: @user3413046 if you can't even tell us enough to explain why the current structure is so essential, this is a very difficult question to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an empty object, bypassing `__init__` by using `__new__`.

```
obj = obj_type.__new__(obj_type)
```

Note that `obj_type` is the appropriate `type` object. This is a little hacky but it works. You are reponsible for setting the object's members.

Edit: here is an example.

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 2

    def say_hello(self):
        print('Hello!')

r = Foo.__new__(Foo)

r.say_hello()

print(r.x)
```

Console output:

```
Hello!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.3.5.7\python-
    3.3.5.amd64\Scripts\projects\luc_utils\dev\test\
unit_test_serialization.py", line 29, in <module>
print(r.x)
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Comment: Sorry I'm still traveling , no access to a pc right now, do the instances methods still work as you mentioned setting the members is to be done manually?

Comment: Hello.  I think that my example may answer your question.  Let me know if it doesn't.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem. It was a neat little trick I ran across in a great book called Python Cookbook 3rd Edition by O'Reilly press.  You can read it for free at the link below, but I highly recommend purchasing a hard copy.  It's killer.  http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000393

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options:

1. Refactor the file loading out to a *class method*, which is the Pythonic method of providing an alternate constructor (see below); or
2. Provide an additional parameter to `__init__` to suppress the exceptions when necessary (e.g. `def __init__(self, folderPath, suppress=False)`, or `validate=True`, whichever makes more sense for your usage).

The latter is a bit awkward, in my opinion, but would mean that you don't have to refactor existing code creating `A` instances. The former would look like:

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self, ...):
        """Pass whatever is loaded from the file to __init__."""
        ...

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, folderPath):
        """Load the data from the file, or raise an exception."""
        ...
```

and you would replace e.g. `a = A(whatever)` with `a = A.from_file(whatever)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very useful module called `mock`, you can check it out later, I feel that in this case it will be too much. Instead, you should consider redesigning your class, like this, for example:

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self, folderPath):
        self.folderPath = folderPath

    def _load_records(self)
        #check folder path using os.isdir() otherwise raise exception
        ...
        #uses self.folderPath and raises exceptions as well
        ...

    @classmethod
    def load_records(cls, folderpath):
        obj = cls(folderpath)
        obj._load_records()
        return obj

    # Usage
    records = A.load_records('/path/to/records')
```

Then you can do:

```
class TestA(unittest.TestCase):
   .......
   obj = None
   def setUp(self):
        self.obj = A('fake folder path')
        self.obj.val1 = "testparam1"
        self.obj.param2 = "testparam2"

   def test_1(self):
        self.assertRaises(self.obj._load_records, HorribleFailureError)
```

Also i highly recommend to check out [pytest](http://pytest.org), it has wonderful facilities for test fixtures, including fixtures for files and folders.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the detailed answer but unfortunately I can't avoid loading records outside the constructor. Not my decision to do that but is there any work around to suppress exceptions?

Comment: Of course. Like I suggested, look at `mock` module or `pytest` fixtures. Both can be a little complicated for a beginner though, so good luck. You can also use https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html to provide real files for input.